# How to set the opencpu default port for single user

Tags: r, opencpu

I am working with opencpu. I installed the opencpu as a single user mode. When the session is expired the link is down and sometimes the port number is changing dynamically. I would like the port to be constant during every run even the current session is expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the port when you start the single user server:

```
library(opencpu)
opencpu$stop()
opencpu$start(1234)
```

This will start opencpu on port 1234. I recommend you try the cloud server, which always runs on port 80 (http) and 443 (https).

Comment: I need another help from you Jeroen

Comment: is there any way to change the default configuration at `.opencpu.conf`?