# Problems Running OpenCPU on a Specified Port

Tags: r, read-eval-print-loop, opencpu

My goal is to access the OpenCPU when I start the browser, e.g. `localhost:7978/ocpu/`. However, I have problems changing the port to a predictable setting. By default, my localhost server randomizes the port number.

I tried the following — [How to set the opencpu default port for single user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647584/how-to-set-the-opencpu-default-port-for-single-user) in my `.Rprofile`:

```
library('stats')
library('opencpu')
opencpu$start(7978)
```

However, opencpu will simply repeat whatever command it is being fed, without reaching a REPL state. I run R from a `.bat` file without arguments.

I also had a look at `.opencpu.conf` but did not become much wiser.

---

**EDIT**

I was not aware that the version of opencpu I was working with started the REPL when loading the package using the library command. I should have read the manual...

**Solution** (OpenCPU < v2.0 ?):

```
library(opencpu)
opencpu$stop()
opencpu$start(7978)
```

However, since the API and function call have since changed, I chose Jeroen's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has changed in the OpenCPU 2.0 release. You now do:

```
ocpu_start_server(port = 5656)
```